# How to lock down wordpress admin login

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming

I created a wordpress site recently, but I am not happy that anybody can be able to view the /wp-admin area. I want to be able to prevent this, what I have in mind is to delete the wp-admin folder, but I believe there would be a better way to prevent everybody from access to this folder.

I would appreciate all help on this topic thanks....

Comment: Why would you delete the `admin` folder ? If you do so, then it won't work anymore and how would you login ? None can login without an account and login requires valid `username` and `password` so don't worry.

Comment: deleting temporarily, uploading it when needed, but I know that would just be crazy, that is why am here

Comment: This is insane, don't you even think about it man.

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge that is absolutely ridiculous to do. There are tons of plugins that can lock down the admin area. This nor is WordPress answers a place to ask for plugin suggestions.

Comment: If you're worried about security then try installing the W[P Better Security](http://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) plugin. It can be tempromental based on your hosting environment, so use it with care.

Comment: is there no way of writing a .htaccess file to do this? I think there should be, am not just that good with server stuffs

Comment: It's ok, on `SO` there are thousands of questions/answers are available about [WordPress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) but it has a seperate site/community as well.

Comment: To sum up previous posts in [wordpress.se] and also discussions at [\[wp-hackers\]](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/) list: it's security by obscurity and totally irrelevant. See [search results](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=protect%20wp-admin).

Comment: @Anagio Those plugins have also one star, since they ruined the sites of several users. So a plugin might be a risk for the wordpress site integrity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to completely block the login page from everyone but yourself then the simplest way I can think of off the top of my head (assuming it's an apache server) would be to simply block access to it through the `.htaccess` file. Add this to the .htaccess file in your WordPress root.

```
<Files wp-login.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    # this should be your IP
    Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Files>
```

You can add as many `Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` lines with different IPs as you like.

If you have a static IP and only access `wp-login.php` from one location then you would never need to change the rules. If your IP changes frequently then you would need to keep chaing it within the .htaccess file (which I assume you will be OK with considering you were looking at removing and re-uploading the whole wp-admin directory).

Comment: Yeah thanks that is exactly what I want, the problem is I do not understand much of what the code is saying, but it works, I would like to know of any resource that explains how to write .htaccess files, thanks so much

Comment: I'll try find a good resource that explains how to work with .htaccess files for you shortly, but here's a quick rundown of what that code does:

The first line tells it that 'these rules apply to just these files'. The only file you need to block is wp-login.php.

The next line says to that the order of permissions is Deny then Allow - meaning you can over-ride deny rules with allow.

Next line says 'deny access to this file from all locations'

The Allow line states that just the specified IP is allowed to access it.

Comment: I found a pretty expansive article here on [NetTuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files/) that details a lot of the ins and outs of how .htaccess works as well as shows you some of the more common uses.

This article here on [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file) is less expansive but a lot easier to read and understand. And as always the official documentation from [Apache on .htaccess files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) has a wealth of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting plugin too: [All In One WP Security & Firewall](http://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/)